# SSL working in chrome but sometimes in Firefox and not on IOS, Android or Blackberry

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, mobile

I have an SSL issue. I have moved a site from one server to another and therefore had to move the SSL. Unfortunately, the new server has a different root domain than the original server. (example - original was www.domain.com and the new is www.domainisnew.com). I have multiple sites using this SSL Certificate.

Trustwave verified the SSL and issued me a new one. I installed it and everything seems to be working fine for me except that sometimes on Firefox I receive an untrusted site warning. I receive the same warning on IOS, Andriod and Blackberry, but everything is perfectly fine on desktop Chrome.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue before?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sound like a case of missing chain certificates.
Chrome usually downloads missing certificates while Firefox does not. But Firefox on desktop caches chain certificates it finds in other connections so it works if the user visited other sites before which used the same chain certificates. On Android the browsers usually neither cache nor download chain certificates. Don't know about iOS and Blackberry, but it might be that they don't cache too.

Check your site against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for chain issues.

Comment: This is exactly what the issue was. Thanks!

Comment: I had to use fullchain.pem instead of cert.pem. try `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443` to see the real issue. you can replace your domain with google.com to see how yours is different.

Answer (score 0):

When you buy certificate you boy it for specify domain name here i see you change domain name so you should buy new one. If you buy [wildcard certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) you will be able to add more sub-domain for your domain but domain must be same.

However, I have this problem earlier on my site. It works on chrome but on ff didn't. Problem was in google analytic and alexa scripts. After update to new one problem was solved.
Also you can check if some of included scripts may have http instead https on internal links.